# Non-trapezoidal rotate3d video issue

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Probably I understand things wrong, but I am facing an issue in my iPhone, testing 3d rotation of .mov video.

Code without rotation:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<video autoplay loop muted playsinline src="vid.mov" style="position:absolute;top:10px;background:transparent;">Support!</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Code with rotation:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<video autoplay loop muted playsinline src="vid.mov" style="position:absolute;top:10px;transform:rotateY(40deg);background:transparent;">Support!</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

I have been trying `rotate3d` `perspective(100px)` `-webkit-transform` - the result is the same.

Why it is not trapezoidal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the perspective property to the parent of the element that is rotated. In this case, the body:

```
body {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Edit: Yeah it can also be applied to the element

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  /* perspective function in transform property */
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, `transform:perspective(1000px) rotateY(40deg);` works, thanks. Earlier, seems, I wrote it separately.